# Is there way in postgresql how to use dynamic table partition name in select?

Tags: postgresql

I have very large table partitioned by date into quarter chunks for performance reasons.
I would like to write sql query that uses dynamic partition name based on which one is the most recent one.
Is there some way how to write this?

example:

partitions names look like this:

```
schema.table_2020_q4
schema.table_2020_q3
schema.table_2020_q2
schema.table_2020_q1
schema.table_2019_q4
schema.table_2019_q3
...
```

today is 2020-07-23 = 2020 Q3, so my sql will look like this:

```
select * from schema.table_2020_q3
```

when app will run this query on 2020-10-01, it needs to be:

```
select * from schema.table_2020_q4
```

Thanks

Comment: How exactly is the table partitioned? Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement. Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your table is indexed by that date, so make the date a part of your `WHERE`expression (in the same format you use for partitioning) and the database should do it automatically.